# Mysqli prepared statement executing properly but no resultset

Tags: php, mysqli

In my `php` application using mysqli prepared statement to execute select query and it is executing properly but it not return any resultset.

```
public static function SelectByRegno($regno) {
    $foo = new Tapal_OutdwardDB();
    echo $regno;
    $myarray = array();

    $statement = $foo->mysqli->prepare("select type,subtype,regno,name,dept,despatchaddress,dealing,ddate,remarks from tapaldespatch where regno=? ");
    $statement->bind_param('S',$regno);
    $statement->execute();
    echo $statement->fullQuery; 
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $myarray[] = $row;  
    } 
    return $myarray;
}
```

The above code is worked in other application created by me. But, here i am facing problem, so please give me solution.

Comment: are you sure that data exists where you are fetching it from?

Comment: i CHECKED DATA EXIST